# How to store trained tensorflow model in database

Tags: mongodb, tensorflow

I need to store trained tensorflow model (either .pb and .h5) into a database (mongoDB). I am able to store using pickled models from sklearn, xgboost etc by refering to below article. But I am not able to store .pb or .h5 files in mongoDB successfully. Can someone please suggest how can this be done?

https://medium.com/up-engineering/saving-ml-and-dl-models-in-mongodb-using-python-f0bbbae256f0

Comment: Maybe you can try to keep the model as it is after converting the model with **tensorflow.js** instead of storing it in database. Once in my project, I loaded the model in an angular application in same way.

Comment: @VaibhavGattyani Thanks for the response. My requirement is to store the model in a database because the application I am working on requires lot of trained models and I need place to store them.